# Head Tags have broken page

Tags: html, css

Ever since i added head tags to my webpage the CSS has broken(divs are misplaced, id's and classes are being applied). Below is an example, any idea why the CSS would be broken?  When i was using span tags the CSS worked but since using head tags the CSS for the whole page has broken.

```
 <head><style type="text/css">   
     h1{
    color:#000000; font-size:28px; font-family:Arial;
    }
    </style></head>


<body>
 <p><h1>$title</h1></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have conflicting selectors?

Comment: Can you use ' instead of " in HTML? I mean the <style type='text/css'> should maybe be <style type="text/css">

Comment: originaly was using span tags.  Then when i switched to using head tags.  The whole page CSS layout/font/styles has broken down.  The CSS isn't working anymore?

Comment: @Indrek That does not matter. Single and double quotes are valid attribute markers. user892134: You have to show all (relevant code). Ideally, you would create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show your problem.

Comment: You mean you never had `<head></head>` before? How did you get away with that?

Comment: The head is optional - it's just a tag like any other. The default style sheet for it is set to `display:none;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't put `<h1>` elements in `<p>` elements, so if you had `<span>`s there first, it would have worked better. Take the `<h1>` out of the `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add html tag  at the very top and replace single quotes with double quotes

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></html>
```

Comment: 1) We presume that this snippet is only part of the OP's webpage. 2) Single quotes are perfectly valid. 3) if you put `</html>` directy after your `<html>`, you are introducing serious defects in the integrity of the page.

Comment: yep this is just a basic example. All i did was add h1 {//code } to my css file and <h1>//content </h1> to my webpage and suddenly the CSS has stopped working

Comment: The html element is optional.